# The Last Kingdom: how does this character end up at this location?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-last-kingdom

In [The Last Kingdom S1E8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Last_Kingdom_episodes#Series_1_(2015)), Uhtred discovers his infant son dead and buried at his farmstead.

**How did the child end up (back) at the farmstead?**

Unless I missed something, the last time the child was shown was departing with his mother, Mildrith, to Odda's estate. Is it the case that someone brought the child back, after his death, to Uhtred's farmstead, specifically for burial?

(I guess I'm trying to bridge the gap with my assumption that the child would have been buried wherever was closest and appropriate - so somewhere on Odda's estate, for example, travel being more difficult and labor-intensive in that era)

Comment: Yes, travel was more difficult and expensive in that era.  But if I remember correctly the era is that of Alfred the Great.  When Alfred the Great was a child his rather took him on a pilgrimage to Rome, which should have been a lot longer 
 trip than taking a child's body from Odda's estate to Uhtred's farmstead.